# jQuery Mobile - trigger("create") removing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, triggers

This code gets generated by a javascript function and inserted onto a page:

```
<div id="user">
    <div class="ui-grid-a"> ... </div>
    <div class="ui-grid-b"> ... </div>
    <div class="ui-grid-solo"> ... </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I run `$("#user").trigger("create");` and that whole section of the DOM is removed. If I delete the `<div data-role="collapsible"></div>` though, the thing runs just fine.

What could be causing this? I'm completely stuck.

Comment: Please add more details, JQM version, js code...etc